# How do I apply a function between two data frames in R and save the output?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Here is some sample data:

```
library(nlme)
library(dplyr)
dat<-read.table(text="time gluc starch solka
1 6.32 7.51 1.95
2 20.11 25.49 6.43
3 36.03 47.53 10.39
6 107.52 166.31 27.01
12 259.28 305.19 113.72
24 283.40 342.56 251.14
48 297.55 353.66 314.22", header = TRUE)
long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, -1, values_to = "y")
long$name <- factor(long$name)
st0 <- list(Max = 200, k = 0.1, Lag = 0.5)
kinetics<-nlsList(y ~ (time > Lag) * Max * (1-exp(-k * (time - Lag))) | name, long, start = st0)
coeff <- data.frame(sample = names(kinetics), coef(kinetics), row.names = NULL)
model.data <- c(1:72)
model.data <- as.data.frame(model.data)
model.data <- rename(model.data, time = model.data)
```

I am trying to fill out `model.data` by applying Max, k, and Lag from `coeff` across time, according to the nls model specified for `kinetics`, so that I would end up with a dataframe like:

[image]

I've found similar questions but nothing with people trying to do something quite this complicated. Thank you

edited to include packages

Comment: Please include the packages you are using in your question. `nlsList` and `rename` are non-base R functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to `predict` values based on your given time.

```r
predict(kinetics, model.data)
```

will bring you a vector similar to your desired output. Using `dplyr` for example, you are able to transform this vector into a data.frame matching your output:

```r
kinetics %>%
  predict(model.data) %>%
  matrix(ncol=3) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  bind_cols(model.data, .) %>%
  select(time, gluc = X1, solka = X2, starch = X3)
```

returns

```r
   time      gluc       solka    starch
1     1   0.00000   0.0000000   0.00000
2     2   0.00000   0.0000000   0.00000
3     3  26.53060   0.0000000  44.11962
4     4  67.27747   0.0000000  96.19380
5     5 101.94559   0.7331433 139.50922
6     6 131.44181  22.1918236 175.53908
7     7 156.53769  42.2833321 205.50880
8     8 177.88968  61.0947739 230.43769
9     9 196.05632  78.7077045 251.17359
10   10 211.51280  95.1984830 268.42177
11   11 224.66343 110.6386039 282.76884
12   12 235.85221 125.0950065 294.70276
13   13 245.37181 138.6303653 304.62943
14   14 253.47124 151.3033617 312.88646
15   15 260.36238 163.1689383 319.75467
16   16 266.22547 174.2785373 325.46766
```